# VueJS: unable to update a component property from inside a watcher

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am building a Vue 2 Webpack application that uses Vuex. I am trying to update a component's local state by watching a computed property which is getting data from the Vuex store. This is what the inside of the `<script></script>` section of my component looks like:

```
export default {
    name: 'MyComponent',

    data() {
        return {
            // UI
            modal: {
            classes: {
                'modal__show-modal': false,
            },
            tags: [],
            },
        };
    },

    computed: {
        tagList() {
            return this.$store.getters.tagList;
        },
    },

    watch: {
        tagList: (updatedList) => {
            this.modal.tags = updatedList;
        },
    },
};
```

As you can see, I have a computed property called tagList which fetches data from the store. I have a watcher that watches tagList so that whenever the store's data changes, I can update `modal.tags` to the new value.

As per [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers), I can call `this.propertyName` and update my local component state but when I call `this.modal.tags = updatedList;`, I get the following error:

`[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "tagList": "TypeError: Cannot set property 'tags' of undefined"`

Why does this error occur even though it looks no different than what is in Vue.js's documentation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use arrow functions.

Change from:

```
watch: {
    tagList: (updatedList) => {
        this.modal.tags = updatedList;
    },
},
```

To:

```
watch: {
    tagList(updatedList) {              // changed this line
        this.modal.tags = updatedList;
    },
},
```

Vue docs mention this [a few times](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks):

> Don't use [arrow
> functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
> on an options property or callback, such as `created: () => console.log(this.a)` or `vm.$watch('a', newValue => this.myMethod())`.
> Since arrow functions are bound to the parent context, `this` will not
> be the Vue instance as you'd expect, often resulting in errors such as
>
> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function
> ```

It is basically a context/scope issue. When using arrow functions, the `this` does not refer to the Vue instance, but the enclosing context of where the component was declared (probably `window`).

Answer (score 2):

That is because of the scope issue. You are calling `this.` from another context. So, within arrow functions, you don't have access to vuejs data.

I suggest you change the watch to:

```
tagList (updatedList) {
    this.modal.tags = updatedList;
},
```